# getting a powershell function reference by string as block

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get a handler added to a form/wpf button by Add_Click.
I do not know the function name beforehand, so constructing the function name is important. Then passing it to Add_Click.

Trying the following, I get

```
$num = 1
function somefn1 () {}

$fn = $Function:"somefn$num"

$somebutton.Add_Click($fn)
```

The error is

```
Cannot convert argument "value", with value: "somefn1", for "add_Click" to type "System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler": "Cannot convert the 
"somefn1" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler"."
At xyz
+ ... $somebutton.Add_Click("somefn$num") }
+                              ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument
```

I am not sure, how to get around that. Any ideas or hints?

Comment: I think you're making this too complicated. `Add_Click` takes a scriptblock as a parameter and you can just specify the function name there, along with the input parameter: `$somebutton.Add_Click({somefn1 $script:$num })` Note that an event handler has its own scope that doesn't include $num as part of it. That's why I added the `$Script:` scope name prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working: using a string to attach an existing function (mind the scope of the handler)

```
$elName = "theButton"  # => Name="theButton"
$fnName = "mynamespace." + "function_name"

$fns = Get-ChildItem function: | Where-Object { $_.Name -like $fnName }
$Form.FindName($elName).Add_Click( $fns[0].ScriptBlock )

function mynamespace.function_name($Sender, $EventArgs) {
  Write-Host "works !"
}
```

Comment: why so complicated? why not just: $somebtn.Add_Click(  (Get-ChildItem function:$fnName).ScriptBlock  )